# Review audit failed (solution was inside the question, not in a separate answer)

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34213488), and I'm very curious to know the reason(s).
I clicked "Share feedback", planning to invite the author to write a separate answer. (I have read such things several times in comments.)
So it's acceptable to put the working solution inside a question?

Comment: And Thom A nailed it. Edits should fix the problem going forward

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To put my comments into an answer before I forget, the audit wasn't a "good" audit. The question has (had) a high score and so the system automatically determined the question was "good" and thus anything other than "looks ok" was considered a failure.

The reason the question had a high score is likely due to "me too" votes; there were at least 3 comments that all were basically "Thanks, I had this problem too" (for transparency I flagged these as no longer needed).

The user was asked to migrate their answer, in the question, to an answer but they ignored that request. As a result I have instead removed the "solution" from the answer and posted a community wiki answer with the OP's answer. This moves the content into an answer, where it is supposed to be.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587